# When using areas, does it make sense to have controllers in a non-area?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If I decide to use areas in mvc3, in a new application, does it make sense to have controllers in a non-area?

Or will that make things inconstant?

This is a new project, and i havent' worked with areas so not sure of how things will end up so looking for advice now.

So far I have an /admin area setup.

I can have code organized into areas, and still have the url with the area name prefixed correct?

Comment: Use what makes sense to you and your team.

Comment: Or.. try and find advice from the community as to what is considered best practice.. crazy idea..

Answer (score 0):

You can have your controllers in your main app if you so choose, with other areas separated out. Its up to you, there's no reason you can't or shouldn't.

"I can have code organized into areas, and still have the url with the area name prefixed  correct?"

Absolutely

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to this in the past. In my solution I had several area's which may or may not contain the controller required. When registering the area you can use the UseNamespaceFallback option. This allows the controller factory to look at other namespaces in the event that the controller isn't found in the area.

```
context.MapRoute(
"Admin_default",
"Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
new[] {"Proj.Web.Controllers.Areas.Admin"}
).DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = true;
```

Then in the Global.asax file add the namespaces for the default controllers.

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Clear();
ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("Proj.Web.Controllers");
ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("Proj.Web.Controllers.Areas.Base");
```

If you want an area to only use controllers within it, simply do DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false. This method has worked great in our solution as it's a very generic based implementation with large amounts of code reuse.

Answer (score 0):

I think it often does make sense to have controllers in a non-area.

For example, if you ever implement a base abstract controller that your area-based controllers will inherit from, I would put something like this in the root (non-area) controllers folder.

Depending on your app, you may also find that you have controllers which span multiple areas. For example, you might have a controller with child actions for navigation. Putting this into a dedicated Navigation area might be overkill, if the area would contain only 1 controller.